# Enquiry on Dell U2720Q setup

Tags: audio, display

I have just bought a Dell U2720Q and a soundbar AC511M. However, after I unboxed them, I found that the only upstream port for U2720Q is a Type-C, while the soundbar provided a Type-A wire. As I wish the soundbar can play audio when connecting to different devices, the soundbar needs to connect to the type-C port of the monitor. And there I need to get a suitable adapter. Although I have bought one, it does not work. Anyone can advice one for me?

[U2720Q Port Overview - Bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t1PQ.png)

My ideal setup would be like

1. Soundbar <--> Monitor *(Need to get a suitable adapter, and connect to Type-C)*
2. Monitor <--> Laptop *(Currently using Type-C to Type-C, later will use adapter to connect to Monitor)*
3. Monitor <--> Desktop *(Currently using DP to DP)*
4. Monitor <--> Nintendo Switch *(Currently using HDMI to HDMI)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the two products, it doesn't look like you need to connect the soundbar to the monitor with USB-C. Just connect the soundbar to one of the USB-A ports on the monitor to power the speakers, and use a 3.5mm cable to connect the line out on the monitor to the soundbar. Then any sources you plug into the monitor should output through the soundbar, and you can switch sources as you please.

Comment: Got it and it works, as the AC511M does not provide the 3.5mm wire and when i sought help from Dell CS, they asked me to plug in the USB to the device I would like to display on the monitor, I did not try it.